# Android Manifest does not detect xml file

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.forms

I am developing app with Xamarin.Forms. I am using [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to access my phone camera. As it is described in documentation, I am supposed to create new folder in Resources file and then add file provider configuration in my AndroidManifest file. For some reason, I get the error:

failed processing manifest.
resource xml/file_paths(aka com.companyname.client:xml/file_paths) not found.
This error is likely caused by and issue with the AndroidManifest.xml or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file.

I spent some time trying to find the issue but without any luck. My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.client" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="Client.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application android:label="client">

    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.client.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

The file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

As I can see in solution explorer, file path is indeed Client.Android/Resources/xml/file_paths.xml

Comment: I have checked the location and the tags in the Mainfest. It should be ok. Have you create a new project to test? And try to use `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` instead.

Comment: I just created new project and set the xml file and the AndroidManifest, its still gives me the error. Is it OK to have multiple <application> tags in the manifest?

Comment: Only the `<manifest>` and `<application>` elements are required. They each must occur only once. Add your `provider ` into previous `<application>` and remove another one.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the BuildAction of file_paths.xml file.

Change:

```
AndroidResourceAnalysisConfig
```

To:

```
 AndroidResource
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.companyname.app1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="Client.Android"
    android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: Your manifest generates for me the same error